# Knockout.Mapping and EcmaScript 5 get set

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, ecmascript-5

ko.mapping can transform [get, set property's (ES5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters) in single ko.computed ?

```
var people = { 
    get Name (){ 
        return this._name;
    },
    set Name(value){
        this._name = value;
    } 
};
var vm = ko.mapping(people, {/* mapping getset to computed */});
vm.Name instanceOf ko.computed === true.
```

ko.mapping support this or how do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you mean to use an observable, not a computed, as this would not depend on other observables.

I created [a gist, including tests,](https://gist.github.com/4274461) of creating models with observable properties, and some utilty functions to create them. The core code is here:

```
var defineProperty = function(type, obj, prop, def) {
  if (obj == null || typeof obj != 'object' || typeof prop != 'string') {
    throw new Error('invalid arguments passed');
  }

  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(def) === '[object Array]' && type === 'observable') {
    type = 'observableArray';
  }

  var obv = ko[type](def);
  Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
    set: function(value) { obv(value) },
    get: function() { return obv() },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });

  Object.defineProperty(obj, '_' + prop, {
    get: function() { return obv },
    enumerable: false
  });
};

ko.utils.defineObservableProperty = defineProperty.bind(null, 'observable');
ko.utils.defineComputedProperty = defineProperty.bind(null, 'computed');

ko.observableModel = function(defaults) {
  for (var prop in defaults) {
    if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (defaults[prop] != null && typeof defaults[prop] == 'object' && Object.prototype.toString.call(defaults[prop]) !== '[object Array]') {
        // should this also be an observable property?
        this[prop] = new ko.observableModel(defaults[prop]);
      } else if (!defaults[prop] || !ko.isSubscribable(defaults[prop])) {
        ko.utils.defineObservableProperty(this, prop, defaults[prop]);
      } else {
        this[prop] = defaults[prop];
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Very nice example !
Not quite what I had in mind, but it helped a lot.
My goal is to really connect to get / set the view, I did a project on github to continue or perhaps something in the increment ko.mapping: [project](https://github.com/barroso/ko_get_set_es5)
Thanks.

Comment: FYI... Since the observable is a function, you don't need to set a wrapper around it... you can just link to it directly (ie get: obs, set: obs), which means you can then set/read your observable values without needing parenthesis...